# Change PopupMenu MenuItem's into custom ones?

Tags: android, menuitem, popupmenu

Is there a way to use custom view in PopupMenu?

Im adding the items to the menu in this way:

```
MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, Menu.NONE,"blabla");
```

Now, what can I do with "item"?

I succeeded change the title, and turn it into checkable one.
but I want more than that

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I ended up with ListPopupWindow:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html

Answer (score 0):

#### You should take a look at [building custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog). In Android, a Dialog is typically in the form of a popup window. You can also do this with an Activity and apply the Dialog theme to it (mentioned in this link).

Comment: Yeah I know about that, but I don't wanna lose the anchoring ability of the Popup